# Java&Maven - Настройка Maven в Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, maven, eclipse

Я новичок в Java, и чего то большого в этой сфере не знаю. В общем решил я написать какой то проект, в моем случае это бот под Discord. Использовать хочу JDApi. Погуглил как установить JDA. Узнал, что делается это через Maven. Изначально я использовал IDEA. Там я установил всё без проблем, но потом перешел на Eclipse, т.к IDEA для моего компьютера слишком тяжелая. Вот тут и начались проблемы, в гугле есть туториалы по установке Maven зависимостей в Eclipse, но в них я не особо разобрался. 
Делаю я всё так.

> Создать новый проект > Maven Project > Skip archetype select >
>   указываю данные зависимости(GroupID etc.) > редактирую pom.xml
>   файл(нужно что бы добавить репозитории)

И дальше не особо понимаю что делать, по идее

> ПКМ по pom.xml > Maven > Maven build.

Но в нем выскакивают ошибки.

Может кто то рассказать, как правильно настроить Maven в Eclipse? Заранее спасибо

pom.xml файл:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
  <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.1_153</version>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
            <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1_153</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jcenter</id>
            <name>jcenter-bintray</name>
            <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Функция Maven build:

> [ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format : or :[:]:. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
>   [ERROR]

Класс с методом:
[image: Main class]

Comment: Если пишете, что выскакивают ошибки, сразу кидайте ошибки)
У меня eclipse жрет в полтора раза больше памяти, чем idea, какой-то странный переход в целях повышения производительности)

Comment: @SmellyNS а вот у меня наоборот, у меня 2ГБ озу, и с запущенной IDEA остается 80-90%, а с Eclipse 50-60%. Ошибки выскакивают по типу не установлен goal, иногда пишет build success. Nothing to compile

Comment: К тому же у maven огромное количество утилит существует для сборки и компиляции. Всё зависит от ошибок. И как по мне вы как-то усложнили процесс добавления зависимости. Всё что нужно - это добавить пару строк об этой зависимости в pom.xml. Я бы лучше ручками это делал, чтобы иметь полный контроль над тем, что именно и куда я добавляю

Comment: @SmellyNS если усложнил, то я делал всё по туториалам из гугла. Я с Maven вообще не умею работать, допустим создал pom.xml файл, вписал туда зависимости с репозиторием, а что дальше делать?

Comment: Вы лучше отредактируйте вопрос и добавьте стэктрейс ошибки, ваш pom.xml, ваш класс, в котором вы вызываете злосчастный метод. А то так надо экстрасенсов искать, а не джава-девелоперов)

Comment: Если быть точным, то из класса интересуют пакеты, импорты, сигнатуры класса и метода, в котором идет вызов метода. И собственно сам вызов метода.

Comment: @SmellyNS добавил pom.xml файл и ошибку. Про "классы" не совсем понял, что я должен добавить

Comment: класс, в котором вы вызываете метод из библиотеки, которая не подгружается

Comment: Для начала вам нужно представление что такое мавен и как он работает) Ошибка заключается в том, что мавен не знает как именно собирать проект, потому что вы не сказали. Почитайте про то, как собирать простейшие проекты maven, например [здесь](https://spring-projects.ru/guides/maven/)

Comment: @SmellyNS Я всё равно не совсем понял, что от меня требуют, вроде как прикрепил класс

Comment: Не прикрепляйте сюда код скриншотами) тут есть форматирование для листингов. вам нужно добавить поле <build> ... </build> в ваш pom.xml. То есть объяснить, как проект-то билдить) В ссылке, которую я дал вам выше, для этого используется плагин shade. Вы можете установить целью jar файл или что-то еще. Так или иначе, сначала вам нужно разобраться, как это все работает